# Magento 2 Configurable product additional plus price showing - unsure where price is coming from

Tags: magento2.2, configurable-product, product-prices

Got a strange scenario where getting plus prices showing in configurable dropdown.

These are simples associated to a configurable product.

[image]

Not seeing anywhere where these plus prices are defined. Reverted to default template just to make sure not templating issue.

Confirmed correct price coming through on basket.

These are not the configuration prices.

[image]

Where are these prices plus (+) prices coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/17695

And fixed in https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/22535

In our case just removed the

```
                        if (typeof allowedProducts[0] !== 'undefined' &&
                            typeof optionPrices[allowedProducts[0]] !== 'undefined') {
                            allowedProductMinPrice = this._getAllowedProductWithMinPrice(allowedProducts);
                            optionFinalPrice = parseFloat(optionPrices[allowedProductMinPrice].finalPrice.amount);
                            optionPriceDiff = optionFinalPrice - finalPrice;

                            if (optionPriceDiff !== 0) {
                                options[i].label = options[i].label + ' ' + priceUtils.formatPrice(
                                    optionPriceDiff,
                                    this.options.priceFormat,
                                    true);
                            }
                        }
```

in theme override

/app/design/frontend/Xigen/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js